# Using gettext in a form

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

How can I use `gettext` in a form? This isn't working:

```
<%= select f, :gender, [gettext "Male:": "male", 
gettext "Female:": "female"], class: "form-control" %>
```

Comment: Have you tried with parens around the `gettext` functions?

Comment: What do you mean by "parens"?

Comment: It is short for parenthesis. `gettext("Male:")` uses parens, `gettext "Male:"` does not.

Comment: Doesn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot call a function in the key part of the keyword list syntax, but you can pass a list of tuples of 2 Strings:

```
<%= select f, :gender, [{gettext("Male:"), "male"}, 
      {gettext("Female:"), "female"}], class: "form-control" %>
```

From the [documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Form.html#select/4)

> Values are expected to be an Enumerable containing two-item tuples (like a regular list or a map) or any Enumerable where the element will be used both as key and value for the generated select.